# how to setup Apache conf and possibly Passenger to allow more vhosts run off one codebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, apache2, passenger

My codebase segments users on an identifier (OXID) but I would like the segmented users have separate **public** folders, and for me to *take a site down* without harassing other sites - which is why I would like my httpd.conf inclusion to look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ny1.alco.dk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alco/current/sites/user_A/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/alco/current
    SetEnv OXID 23
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ny2.alco.dk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alco/current/sites/user_B/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/alco/current
    SetEnv OXID 25
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache is cool with this - but Passenger barks with "no such file to load -- bundler" - so obviously, this is not right!

Is this at all possible (at least with Apache/2.2.14 (Unix), Ruby 1.8.7 p330, Rails 3.0.3, and Passenger 3.0.2)

Update!
Turns out that the Passenger 'bark' was on me :(

I have the 2 sites up and running - but both sites report the ENV['OXID'] of the first host being accessed!? Ie. if I browse ny1.alco.dk/something - I get '23' which is good, but I also get '23' if I then browse to ny2.alco.dk!? Likewise - if I browse to ny2.alco.dk/something as the first thing after touching tmp/restart.txt, I get '25' which will be the same value I get, when subsequently browsing to ny1.alco.dk - Hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a hack - I'll need to investigate further but:

If I do

```
ln -s /data/www/html/alco/current ny1
ln -s /data/www/html/alco/current ny2
```

and then edit my /data/apache/conf.d/alco.conf to hold

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ny1.alco.dk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alco/ny1/sites/user_A/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/alco/ny1
    SetEnv OXID 23
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ny2.alco.dk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alco/ny2/sites/user_B/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/alco/ny2
    SetEnv OXID 25
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm good :)

I'd still like second opinions on this one - but for now; I'm good :)

Comment: Shute - nothing lasts forever :(
Fresh up with 3.2.0, and my 'hack' is history

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.2.0 includes a `config.ru` which really seems to be the culprit - removing it altogether did solve my multi-site problem.

So, lesson - so far - is that Rails apps do not lend easy to raking if you like to share code between like sites!